# vim in tmux lose highlighting

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm using vim 8.0 and tmux 2.5 on ubuntu.

And I have set the TERM environment `export TERM=screen-256color` and run as `tmux -2`.

Normally, nothing goes wrong. It's like the following picture:

[image: Normal]

But after I move cursor over the right parenthesis several times,
the highlighting will be lost, like the following picture:

[image: lost]

If I run the commands `:NoMatchParen` in vim,
nothing goes wrong.

Is there any solution to it without turning off parenthesis matching?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend asking it on https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Thanks for your advice. I'll move the question to it.